# What is SEO friendly: blog.brandname.com or www.brandname.com/blog?

Tags: domain, subdomain, directory, cname-record, mapping

www.brandname.com is a Rails app hosted at Heroku.
brandname.wpengine.com is a Wordpress blog hosted at WPEngine.

I know I can't use the DNS (CNAME) to map `www.brandname.com/blog` to `brandname.wpengine.com`.
I may map `blog.brandname.com` to `brandname.wpengine.com` instead.

But I've read many posts about subfolder and subdomain and the impact on SEO. Sometimes it seem it doesn't matter, sometimes it does.

So, what about a rack redirect ni the rails app? Someone as answer a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327761/make-an-existing-wordpress-blog-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app

What do you think ? What is the best way to link a Heroku app and a WPEngine blog to maximize SEO?

blog.brandname.com
or
rack redirect?

Cheers

---

ps: edited after MichaelHampton comment.

Comment: You can't do that, it has to be on another domain. And you need better SEO experts. Whoever told you that a subdomain was worse than a directory is full of it. Content is _still_ king.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for your answer. I agree with you, I know I can't use DNS to do that. I think I'll use a subdomain like blog.domain.com.